# ERROR: type Nullable has no field name Julia

Tags: julia

in array i have Object , created by two constructors

```
type Node
  name::AbstractString
  value::Int
  left::Nullable{Node}
  right::Nullable{Node}

  Node(name::AbstractString, value::Int) = new(name, value, Nullable{Node}(), Nullable{Node}())
  Node(name::AbstractString, value::Int, left::Node, right::Node) = new(name, value, left, right)
end
```

When I try to get to the `nodes[1].right.name` I get an error like in topic , but i'm sure is there an Object

```
nodes[1] 
Node("New",15,Nullable(Node("bb",7,Nullable{Node}(),Nullable{Node}())),Nullable(Node("cc",8,Nullable{Node}(),Nullable{Node}())))
```

How can i fix it ?

Edit i type my whole code

```
A = [Node("aa", 11) , Node("bb", 7), Node("cc", 8), Node("d", 11)]

function HuffmanNodes(nodes::Vector{Node})
  while(length(nodes) > 1)
    left = minimal(nodes)
    Left = nodes[left[1]]
    deleteat!(nodes, left)
    right = minimal(nodes)
    Right = nodes[right[1]]
    deleteat!(nodes, right)
    top = Node("New",Left.value+Right.value, Left, Right)
    println(top)
    push!(nodes, top)
    printNodes(top, " ")
  end
end
```

And methods in HuffmanNodes function

```
function printNodes(node::Node, str::AbstractString)
  if(node.name != "New")
    string(node.name, str)
    println(string)
  end
  printNodes(node.left.name , string(str , " 0")
  printNodes(node.right.name , string(str, "  1")
end

function minimal(nodes::Vector{Node})
  minnode = Nullable{Node}()
  minnode = nodes[1]
  minval = nodes[1].value
  for f in nodes
    println(f)
    if f.value < minval
      minval = f.value
      minnode = f
    end
  end
  return find(nodes .==minnode)
end
```

And i trying call `HuffmanCode(A)` and then i get error , i tried with `get(node.right).name` , but it is not wokring

Comment: Please make sure that your code is properly formatted and readable, I cleaned it up a little bit but can't say for sure it's still what you're trying to do (e.g. the `printNodes` function seemed to be missing an `end`). What is the need for the minimal function? I gave you a working version in the other question you asked.

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide a minimum working example? From the code you posted I'm not able to create the `Node` you're trying to access, and I don't really understand what you're trying to do.

In any case, `nodes[1].right` is of type `Nullable`, it's not the node (which would have a `name` attribute). According to [the docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/types/#safely-accessing-the-value-of-a-nullable-object), you should access the value of the `Nullable` object using `get()`, i.e. `get(nodes[1].right)`

Comment: What exactly did you try? What was the error? It's impossible to figure it out just from "not working".

Answer (score 2):

You should use the REPL (i.e. the Julia terminal) to explore the objects you are creating. Here is a sample session after defining the `Node` type like you did, exactly as I wrote it in the terminal as I was exploring the `Node` objects.

In the future, please report *exactly* what you type and *exactly* the resulting error, just by copying and pasting as I did here, and *make your example as simple as possible* without extra detail that does not matter.

```
julia> type Node
              name::AbstractString
              value::Int
              left::Nullable{Node}
              right::Nullable{Node}

              Node(name::AbstractString, value::Int) = new(name, value, Nullable{Node}(), Nullable{Node}())
              Node(name::AbstractString, value::Int, left::Node, right::Node) = new(name, value, left, right)
       end

julia> nodes = [Node("a", 1), Node("a", 2)]
2-element Array{Node,1}:
 Node("a",1,Nullable{Node}(),Nullable{Node}())
 Node("a",2,Nullable{Node}(),Nullable{Node}())

julia> nodes[1]
Node("a",1,Nullable{Node}(),Nullable{Node}())

julia> nodes[1].right
Nullable{Node}()

julia> get(nodes[1].right)
ERROR: NullException()
 in get at nullable.jl:30

julia> nodes[1].right = Node("c", 3)
Nullable(Node("c",3,Nullable{Node}(),Nullable{Node}()))

julia> get(nodes[1])
ERROR: MethodError: `get` has no method matching get(::Node)

julia> get(nodes[1].right)
Node("c",3,Nullable{Node}(),Nullable{Node}())

julia> n = get(nodes[1].right)
Node("c",3,Nullable{Node}(),Nullable{Node}())

julia> n.name
"c"
```